# Windows: Remapping 'Shift + AltGr' to a single key? Easier access to '4th level' characters on international keyboards

Tags: keyboard-layout, autohotkey, international

By holding Shift + AltGr, the 4th level characters can be accessed on international layout on most operating systems:

- C → c (lowercase — first level)
- ⇧ Shift+C → C (uppercase — second level)
- AltGr+C → © (copyright sign — third level)
- AltGr+⇧ Shift+C → ¢ (cent sign — fourth level)

For Windows 10/11, how could change this behaviour so that I can assign a single dedicated key to replace this Shift + AltGr?

For example, on my keyboard, I have a PrtSc (printscreen) key that I don't need, that I could use exclusively as a replacement for Shift + AltGr.

I'm guessing this could be done with Autohotkey. But worried about compatibility/robustness.
Are there any ways that are more direct, lower level?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

; PrintScreen = Shift + AltGr
*PrintScreen::Send {Shift Down}{LCtrl Down}{RAlt Down}
*PrintScreen Up::Send {Shift Up}{LCtrl Up}{RAlt Up}
```